# Rendering my own <script> tag instead of the one provided by JSF

Tags: java, jsf, tags

I have page which consists of couple fragments and in the "header" fragment I have this tag `<webuijsf:script id="script_logo" url="/resources/logo.js"/>`. This is rendered in HTML as `<script src="/app/resources/logo.js" type="text/javascript" id="Header:script_logo"></script>`. This is fine and it is working as expected. Now I need to force JSF somehow to return URL to the javascript with current version of app. This is known technique for forcing the reload of resource (javascript, css and images) in case they are cashed on client's side. I need to render something like `<script src="/app/resources/logo.js?ver=1.0.405" type="text/javascript" id="Header:script_logo"></script>`. Please note the `ver` parameter in the URL.
Thanks.
Tomas

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Well, you can simply add it to the page:

```
<script src="/app/resources/logo.js?ver=#{commonBean.version}" ...>
```

I've assumed you want to version to be configurable and sent by the server, so `commonBean` is some jsf bean that returns the proper version.

Update: also take a look at [`<rich:loadScritp>`](http://docs.jboss.org/richfaces/latest_3_3_X/en/devguide/html/a4j_loadScript.html). (from RichFaces)

The final option is to create your own component and include the version automatically. Look for tutorial for how to make that, it's not easy for JSF 1.2

Comment: I was thinking about something more generic where I don't have to go through the code and add to every occurence of the `<script>` tag some new stuff. Something like servlet which will be mapped to the '/resource/' path and do the trick to add some artificial parameter. Or a new renderer for the `<script>` tag which will do the same as the servlet.

Comment: @Tomas Babic it wouldn't be much of a difference. Anyway, see my update.

Comment: it does make difference. I don't want to go through every page and fragment and update all ocurences of my images, css and scripts tags with this `?ver=#{someBean.version}` code. There has to be more generic aproach.

Comment: @Tomas Babic - you can make your own component. But it's not easy.

Comment: You would be ready in less time than the time you needed for this question :)

Answer (score 0):

Well thats pretty easy. JSF 2 uses a configuration to Bind a renderer to a component.
Therefor you need a component-family and a renderer-type. Now you can define in your
faces-config.xml a renderer for that family and renderer-type.

In Mojorra the following configuration is set for a outputScript-Component:

```
<renderer>
  <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
  <renderer-type>javax.faces.resource.Script</renderer-type>
  <renderer-class>com.sun.faces.renderkit.html_basic.ScriptRenderer</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

I must admit, that this info is coming from my debugging. I debugged the ScriptRenderer
and was able to get the component-family and renderer-type from the UIComponent.

Now if you use an other Renderer for that Component, just change the configuration
and the original will be overwritten:

```
<renderer>
  <component-family>javax.faces.Output</component-family>
  <renderer-type>javax.faces.resource.Script</renderer-type>
  <renderer-class>your.own.renderer.class</renderer-class>
</renderer>
```

Do not forget, all h:outputScript components will render now with the new Renderer.
Same goes with stylesheets, but those will have an other render-type.

Comment: Note that OP is using JSF 1.2 with Woodstock. Your answer is therefore completely inapplicable.